# infected white cell detection in image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

hello i'm a beginner of using `matlab` and as part of my Homework. i need to detect infected white cells in image and count them where the Nucleus of an infected white cell large and color Blue.

Original Image

[image]

Explain Image:

[image]

so i try to isolate the whit cells then detect the infected white cells but i'm stuck and do not what to do i will write my code and mention where i stuck and please if three is anther way to do this pleas help

1. convert the image from `RGB` to `YcBcR` space color to detect the whit sells

   ```
   OrgenalImg = imread('D:\Users\FADI\Desktop\cells\cells1.jpg');

   CopyOfOrgenalImg = OrgenalImg;

    YcbcrImage = rgb2ycbcr(CopyOfOrgenalImg);
    cb = YcbcrImage(:,:,2);
    cr = YcbcrImage(:,:,3);

   [r,c,v] = find(cb>=77 & cb<=127 & cr>=133 & cr<=173);

   index1 = size(r,1);

   %Mark the white cell pixel
   for i=1:index1
     CopyOfOrgenalImg(r(i),c(i),:) = 255;
   end

   figure, imshow(CopyOfOrgenalImg);title('White Cells');
   ```

   the White Cells image:

[image]

2.here i'm stuck i try to convert the White Cells image to gray `grayscale` to delete and remove the unwanted shape but i can't find way to do that so pleas help and how can i continue in my homework to detect and count the with cells and if there is anther ways to do this pleas let me know thanks in advance on any help.

Comment: +1 for showing what you tried and looks interesting too.

Comment: how many training examples do you have? how many test sample do you need to test your algorithm on?

Comment: i just have two image to detect infected white cell in and i'm trying to use the color of the infected cell and the size of it and comparison it withe size of normal white cells to isolate the infected cell from the normal and count them

Comment: since it's only homework and not research, you can hand-pick one blue-ish pixel and write down its YCbCr value (a three-vector), then you can measure the distance of each pixel to that value in YCbCr space and pick a threshold. this should give you a nice mask. use morphological operations to complete the task. `regionprops` may also come in handy. good luck. nice question.

Comment: You can also take a look at watershed segmentation. Here's a good example from mathworks: [link](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/examples/marker-controlled-watershed-segmentation.html)

Comment: check out the "rice" image in the help documentation.  It is used in several examples that require counting.

Answer (score 1):

You might attempt this by thresholding the image based on the blue channel to identify regions corresponding to each cell.  For a non-research/homework exercise this may be sufficent given a carefully chosen threshold (0.66 in code below).  Then you can iterate through each connected component and make a decision based on the area.  In a real-world situation you would train up a system based on some kind of shape descriptor for this, but given you have only 2 example images some kind of hard-coded heuristic like this seems unavoidable.

Here is one solution:

```
INFECTED_AREA_THRESHOLD=3000; 

img=double(imread('\cell.jpg'))./255;
blueness=img(:,:,3)./(img(:,:,1)+img(:,:,2)+img(:,:,3));
blueness=blueness./max(max(blueness));
cellmask=blueness<0.66;

cellmask=bwfill(~cellmask,'holes');

map=bwlabel(cellmask);
labels=setdiff(unique(map),0)';

infectedcomponents=zeros(size(img,1),size(img,2));
areas=[];
infected=0;
for thislbl=labels
    connectedcomp=(map==thislbl);
    thisarea=sum(sum(connectedcomp));
    areas=[areas; thisarea];
    if (thisarea>INFECTED_AREA_THRESHOLD)
        infected=infected+1
        infectedcomponents=infectedcomponents | connectedcomp;
    end
end

imshow(rgb2gray(img).*infectedcomponents);
title(strcat(num2str(infected),' infected components detected'));
sort(areas)
```

The decision to threshold at 3000 was made by inspecting the list of component/cell areas in variable "areas".  The blue threshold of 0.66 was by trial and error.

Sample output:

[image]